# Empty file when saving soapUI response

Tags: file, groovy, soapui

I'm using groovy script in soapUI. I want to save my response to file. I'm using the following script. The file is created, but it's content is empty.

```
//get dir target from property
def dirTarget = context.expand( '${#Project#SnapShotDirTarget}' )

def fileDir = new File(dirTarget);
if(!fileDir .exists()) {
   fileDir .mkdirs()
} 

def currentDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
def fileName = "Snapshot - "+currentDate+".txt"
def resultsFile= new File(fileDir , context.expand( fileName) )

if(!resultsFile.exists()) {
    resultsFile.createNewFile();
}

resultsFile.append("Post URL:"+messageExchange.getEndpoint()+'\n' ); 
resultsFile.append("Request:"+'\n' ); 
resultsFile.append(messageExchange.getRequestContent()+'\n' ); 
resultsFile.append("Response:"+'\n' ); 
resultsFile.append(messageExchange.getResponseContent()+'\n' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Windows the colon between the hour and minutes in the filename is going to cause some problems, since colon is not allowed in Windows file names.

When I tried running the script it created an empty file called "Snapshot - 2014-08-14 09" (everything after and including the colon is missing)

Changing the colon to something else makes the trick.

```
def currentDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd hh_mm")
```

The call to createNewFile is not necessary by the way. The append call will create the file if it doesn't exist.